# Different result in Linq with GroupBy and Count

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this lines of code:

```
IQueryable<AZ_Return_R> fistSet = myDb.AZ_Return_Rs.Where(w => w.Master_Session_ID == 14);
List<AZ_Return_R> secondSet = myDb.AZ_Return_Rs.Where(w => w.Master_Session_ID == 14).ToList();

var res1 = fistSet.GroupBy(g => g.Order_ID).Select(s => new { orderId = s.Key, count = s.Key.Count()});
var res2 = secondSet.GroupBy(g => g.Order_ID).Select(s => new {orderId = s.Key, count = s.Key.Count()});
```

Where `AZ_Return_R` is a table with 2 columns: `Order_ID` and `Master_Session_ID`. The table have 10 records, 5 with `Master_Session_ID = 14` and 5 with `Master_Session_ID = 1`. `Since Order_ID` is unique in the table, I supposed thet res1 and res2 must return 5 records, all with `Count = 1`, insted res1 is correct, res2 return 5 records, but with `Count = 19`!!!
Where I'm wrong?

**EDIT**

I found that if I write:

```
var res3 = secondSet.GroupBy(g => g.Order_ID).Select(s => new { orderId = s.Key, count = s.Count() });
```

the result is correct, so why with List<> I have to use s.Count and with IQueryable<> must be used s.Key.Count ?

Comment: are you shure that you use `count = s.Key.Count()` and not `count = s.Count()`?

Comment: with IQueryable you also must use `s.Count()` instead

Comment: I have never used key.count to be honest, shouldn't each key be unique anyway?

Comment: @AD.Net in this case `Key` should be is `Int`, as i understand, so i don't know why `Key.Count()` work :-)

Comment: the problem is to understand what is counted when instead of s.Count is used s.Key.Count.

Comment: @UnoSolo what is `Order_ID` type?

Comment: nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

Comment: @UnoSolo now clear why your count is work - its return count chars in string

Comment: @Grundy You are right!, thank you very much for solving me this headache!!!. But why when using s.Key.Count() on an IQueryable return the correct result and not still the lenght of the key?

Comment: @UnoSolo That's because it will be translated into `COUNT(order_id)` within generated SQL query.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Hi, I know from your blog that you are a Microsoft Engineer, maybe in the Linq Team. Do you think is correct that when working on an IQueryable, the s.Key.Count() is translated to COUNT(order_id) instead of returning as IEnumerable do the lenght of the key? I think that will be better for uniformity to have the same result/approach. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it was translated to `COUNT(*)` when i test it

Comment: @Grundy OK, good to know! Does it change anything? :) The key here is a fact, that there is an SQL query generated and executed, and that's why results differ. **UnoSolo:** I have nothing to do with Linq Team, and my answers here are just on my own. My employment has nothing to do with that :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it changes when viewed from the point of view of the database, because `Count(fieldname)` should be faster than `Count(*)` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong logic in your sample, when you group by `Order_ID` in next `Select` parameter `s` have property `Key` that same `Order_ID` - string in your case.
So when you call `Key.Count()` in your select then it return string length

so you need change

```
s.Key.Count()
```

to

```
s.Count()
```

**UPDATE**

your solution work for `IQueryable` because it first generate sql script like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count], [t0].[Order_ID] AS [orderId]
FROM [dbo].[TestTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Master_session_ID ] = @p0
GROUP BY [t0].[Order_ID]
```

and execute it when you test result. As you see this sql return correct values

in case `IEnumerable` you first get all items and then use Linq-to-Objects to work with them.

Comment: ok that's right, but why with IQueryable the s.Key.Count() works, and not return the lenght of the key?

Comment: @UnoSolo it depends on your values in table and how you test result. Can you explain it?

Comment: Grundy is easy, build an sql table with 2 fields, 1 nvarchar(50) not null call it order_id, another master_session_ID int. Populate the table with 10 records, 5 records put in master_session_id = 1 and 5 records put master_session_id = 14. In the order_id put 19 chars unique for each record. That's all. The problem is how Linq is handling List<> and IQueryable<>.

Comment: @UnoSolo how you test result? `Select` returns `WhereSelectEnumerator`, you call `ToList()` or something else?

Comment: @UnoSolo what you use LinqtoSql or EF or something else?

Comment: Grundy, I'm using Linq to Sql

Comment: Grundy, yes I understand, but why using GroupBy on the IEnumerable, working on all the records, the Key of the GroupBy is handled differently from the Key in the IQueryable? It seems that IEnumerable don't handle the Key as the Key of the Group, but as a field, so doing s.Key.Count() count the chars of the Key field, and not the occurences in the Key group

Comment: it because used different logic - with `IQueryable` you get result from db by sql query, but for `IEnumerable` you work with objects collection, also see how work [GroupBy extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx)